# Проблема объединения пустых меток

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, метки, модерация, инструменты-модератора

Если открыть [инструмент объединения меток](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/admin/merge-tags) и вбить в поля две пустые метки, например [cli](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cli) и [command-line-interface](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/command-line-interface):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и выполнить объединение, вываливается страница ошибки: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/admin/merge-tags

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Ожидаемое поведение: создание синонима или сообщение о том, что его нельзя создать.

Comment: Интересная ошибка. Добавил в трекер.

Comment: А пустые метки это как?

Comment: @NickVolynkin, честно говоря уже не помню. Наверное, речь шла о метках, в которых нет вопросов.

Comment: @Nofate: на предпросмотре была ошибка?